# Why is this PortName deemed nonexistent?

Tags: c#, serial-port, compact-framework, windows-ce, port-number

I'm trying to refactor/update some legacy serial comm code. I've got this:

```
private SerialPort cereal;
private String receivedData;

private FileXferLegacy()
{
    cereal = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600);
    cereal.PortName = "7727";
    cereal.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);
    // Is this just as well, as the elided part is grayed out above?: cereal.DataReceived += port_DataReceived;
}
```

...but am getting the err msg "*The port '7727:' does not exist*" when I try to connect and send a ping:

```
public void SendDataContentsAsXML(string destinationPath, string XMLData)
{
    byte[] stuff;
    ExceptionLoggingService.Instance.WriteLog("Reached FileXferLegacy.SendDataContentsAsXML"); // <= This is written to the log file
    cereal.Open();
    stuff = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("PING" + "\n");
    cereal.Write(stuff, 0, stuff.Length);
    stuff = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(XMLData + "\n");
    cereal.Write(stuff, 0, stuff.Length);
}
```

7727 is the same port that is successfully used in the legacy app.

I do see that there is a colon appended, and wonder if that is the problem - why is it seeing "7727:"  instead of plain old "7727", and how can I disabuse it of the notion of having an appended colon if that is indeed a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `PortName` refers to the serial port name, not a port number. In your code you're creating your `SerialPort` object

```
cereal = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600);
```

So `COM1` is already being assigned to `PortName`. Your next statement is just overriding it unnecessarily and incorrectly.

Comment: So how can I set the port (not the name of the serial port, but the port on which to send data)? The legacy app uses 7727, so there must be a way to do this, but I see no likely property on the SerialPort class.

Comment: There is no such thing as a port number for serial ports. Serial ports are for single end-to-end connections and therefore have no concept of port numbers; that's for TCP/UDP connections.